# How does comparing BigNumbers with ethers work?

Tags: ethers.js, bignumber

I am using ethers and writing tests and I don't quite understand the ethers.BigNumber.from('some number') method.  Could someone please explain how it works, the documentation is not very helpful to me.
For example:
`console.log(ethers.BigNumber.from('30') < ethers.BigNumber.from('120'));`

returns "false"

Why is BigNumber from 30 greater than BigNumber from 120?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I exactly ran into the same problem. You should use the built.in methods in bignumber:

```
let a = ethers.BigNumber.from('30');
let b = ethers.BigNumber.from('120');
 a.lt(b) // returns true  as 30 is lower than (lt) 120
```

Here you use lt (lower than), you can use:

- eq: equal
- gte: greater or equal
- gt: greater
- lte: lower or equal
- lt: lower

Hope it helps

Comment: oh thank you very much!